# Videojs playlist not work

Tags: video.js, playlist

i have a problem when i try use the playlist plugin of video js like that example:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Playlist Tester Perform</title>
  <style type="text/css">
    .video-js {
      float: left;
      margin: 15px;
      width: 440px;
      height: 280px;
    }
    .vjs-playlist {
      width: 250px;
      float: left;
      margin: 15px;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <video id="myPlayerID"
    data-account="3676484087001"
    data-player="04ac0699-ca6b-449b-a2b6-0f14b4a7893b"
    data-embed="default"
    class="video-js" controls></video>

  <ol class="vjs-playlist"></ol>

  <script src="//players.brightcove.net/3676484087001/04ac0699-ca6b-449b-a2b6-0f14b4a7893b_default/index.min.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    videojs('myPlayerID').ready(function () {
      var myPlayer = this;
      myPlayer.playlist([{
        "sources": [{
          "src": "http://solutions.brightcove.com/bcls/assets/videos/Sea_SeaHorse.mp4", "type": "video/mp4"
        }],
        "name": "Seahorse",
        "thumbnail": "http://solutions.brightcove.com/bcls/assets/images/Sea_Seahorse_poster.png",
        "poster": "http://solutions.brightcove.com/bcls/assets/images/Sea_Seahorse_poster.png"
      }, {
        "sources": [{
          "src": "http://solutions.brightcove.com/bcls/assets/videos/Sea_Anemone.mp4", "type": "video/mp4"
        }],
        "name": "Sea Anemone",
        "thumbnail": "http://solutions.brightcove.com/bcls/assets/images/Sea_Anemone_poster.png",
        "poster": "http://solutions.brightcove.com/bcls/assets/images/Sea_Anemone_poster.png"
      }, {
        "sources": [{
          "src": "http://solutions.brightcove.com/bcls/assets/videos/Tiger.mp4", "type": "video/mp4"
        }],
        "name": "Tiger",
        "thumbnail": "http://solutions.brightcove.com/bcls/assets/images/Tiger_poster.png",
        "poster": "http://solutions.brightcove.com/bcls/assets/images/Tiger_poster.png"
      }, {
        "sources": [{
          "src": "http://solutions.brightcove.com/bcls/assets/videos/Sea_ClownFish.mp4", "type": "video/mp4"
        }],
        "name": "Clownfish",
        "thumbnail": "http://solutions.brightcove.com/bcls/assets/images/Sea_ClownFish_poster.png",
        "poster": "http://solutions.brightcove.com/bcls/assets/images/Sea_ClownFish_poster.png"
      }, {
        "sources": [{
          "src": "http://solutions.brightcove.com/bcls/assets/videos/Sea_LionFish.mp4", "type": "video/mp4"
        }],
        "name": "Lionfish",
        "thumbnail": "http://solutions.brightcove.com/bcls/assets/images/Sea_LionFish_poster.png",
        "poster": "http://solutions.brightcove.com/bcls/assets/images/Sea_LionFish_poster.png"
      }]);
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

When i change the videos links to my local folder ("src": "/files/convert/videos/38472531Test.mp4", "type": "video/mp4"), the playlist doesn't advance to the next video. I think it is a problem of ffmpeg conversion but i'm not sure of that.

PD:The problem is only in the playlist not in the playing

Comment: How are you loading this HTML, and then, what is serving your local content at "/files/convert/..."?  Try opening your browser's web developer tools and observe the network connections.

Comment: The videos are working, the problem is with the playlist.

Comment: I still don't understand your question. Does the playlist work when you use the brightcove urls as shown in your question?  Regardless, still recommending opening your web developer tools and observing network connections and console to see if anything obvious.

Comment: Sorry for my bad english, it isn't my mother tongue. When a video ends , I need to automatically play the next video in the playlist. That works only in the examples videos. My videos play well but when they end, the list doesn't advance to the next video. Do you undestand now? Thanks PD: I find nothing unusual in the network connections

Comment: This might help, see:  https://github.com/brightcove/videojs-playlist `myPlayer.playlist.autoadvance(0);`

Answer (score 0):

i have just been having this same issue. I worked out on mine that if i set the url for the video file to `http://myip/path to video file` instead of giving it a local link to the file mine starts to auto play. Is this the case on yours?

I assume that this is a bug in the playlist plugin but it seems to work as a workaround in my case.